# char array variable name want to use in variable in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

i created char array

```
char Jan1[] = "1,2,3,4";
char Jan2[] = "5,7,3,4";
char Jan3[] = "10,9,3,4";`
```

the above char arrays i want to use it as shown below in for loop each time it will iterate and print, print is an example i am processing this string further in code, but it is giving error. if instead of yy i use Jan1 then it is printing properly. what is the other way i can use yy as to get print char array as string.

```
for(int i=1;i<=2;i++)
{
char yy[4];
sprintf(yy,"Jan%d",i);
String presentMonth = String(yy);
Serial.print(presntMonth);
}
```

Comment: for 4 chars long string you need 5 positions because you need a space for the terminating zero

Comment: i tried with increasing with 10 also but issue is String(yy) it is not taking as Jan1 and returning nothing. how to pass value instead of yy

Comment: Are you mixing up variable names and strings? Do you expect that by writing Jan1 into yy, you will print `1,2,3,4`?

Comment: you don't share the error message, you have at least one typo in your code. I refuse to answer this. put more effort into your question if you want help

Comment: i am not mixing what i want is in for loop i want to fetch the values of Jan1, Jan2 and Jan3 as that is char so wanted to convert it to string and printing. here i cannot hardcode these value in for loop so i tried to keep Jan and increment the number which is in yy. but when it execute this  String presentMonth = String(yy); nothing is showing/printing as output but when i am hard coding the value like String presentMonth = String(Jan1); it is printing the array as sting. so stuck here

Comment: of course you're mixing up things... you're post says it and your comment confirms it. you cannot print the contents of your JanX arrays by building a string "Jan%d"...

Comment: sorry i am unable to convey the issue properly. then what is the way to get all the JanX values ne by one in above for loop

Answer (score 1):

So by the comments it seems that what you want is to print the contents of the `JanX` variable based on an index variable.

### Missunderstanding

First of all you need to understand the difference between strings as **datatypes** and **variable names**. The former are ways to represent a sequence of characters (used mainly, but not only, to display output messages to any sort of output like a file, a console etc..). The latter are names that you use while coding and they can be whatever you want but they will never appear in the final program.

This for instance creates a `String` (datatype) named `hello` which contains the sequence of characters `h e l l o`.

```
String hello = "Hello";
```

Nothing prevents me to assign `goodbye` to it:

```
hello = "Goodbye"
Serial.print(hello); // This will print "Goodbye"
```

In general (apart from very hacky ways) you can't retrieve the name of the variable from your program and have them ready in your executable.

### Issue

```
char Jan1[] = {'1','2','3'};
String yy = "Jan1"
Serial.print(yy); // This will print "Jan1"
```

To print the items in `Jan1` you need to iterate through the values.

```
void printItems(char* s,int N){
  for ( i = 0; i<N; i++ ) 
  { Serial.print(s[i]); } 
}
```

Since Arduino provides the String class, however, it would be better to do this:

```
String Jan1 = "1,2,3,4";
Serial.print(Jan1); // This iterates under the hood, takes care of the length, and all the good stuff.
```

### Solution

You want to do something a little more advanced, you want to point to a particular string based on a variable, then print the content of the retrieved string.

I can think of two ways for doing so: by using an **list of strings** or via a *hashmap*.

#### List of strings

```
String list[] = {"1,2,3,4" , "4,5,6,7", ... };
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(list)/sizeof(String) ; i++ ){
   Serial.print(list[i])
}
```

#### Hashmap

The reason I am thinking about this is because you want a string as the "index" that let's you lookup the string, so you can "search" by name. The easiest and quickest method I can think of is to declare an array of structs `string_name;string_content` and use `strcmp` to iterate through the array of structs until the needed one is found.

```
typedef struct{ String name; String content;} element_t;
element_t dict[] = { {"Jan1","1,2,3,4"} , {"Jan2","2,3,4,5"} ... }'

// Note this is not even close to perfect (for instance lacks check if key does not exists)
String lookup(element_t DICT, int DICT_SIZE, String key){
   // Iterate through the elements, use strcmp to retrieve it
   for(int i = 0; i < DICT_SIZE ; i++ ){
      if(strcmp(DICT[i].name,key) { 
           return DICT[i].content;
      }
   }
}

// Now create the key, as in your code, and then lookup.
for(int i=1;i<=2;i++)
{
char yy[4];
  sprintf(yy,"Jan%d",i);
  String presentMonth = lookup(dict,dict_size,yy);
  Serial.print(presntMonth);
}
```